# rich:column only displaying facets

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, richfaces

According to the richfaces documentations, I should be able to get a column with a header and a footer named "Product" and a single row containing "something" using this code:

```
        <rich:dataTable styleClass="contained_width" rows="3">
            <rich:column>

                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Product" />
                </f:facet>

                something

                <f:facet name="footer">
                    <h:outputText value="Product" />
                </f:facet>

            </rich:column>
        </rich:dataTable>
```

However the line "something" does not appear (I only get the header and the footer).
I haven't found anyone else with that problem...
I am using richfaces 4.5.17, Wildfly 10.1, and JSF 2.2.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**
[screen of what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXWlH.png)

Comment: Your table has no elements (`value` is empty), so no content is rendered. This is perfectly normal.

Comment: @EmilSierżęga so I just put value="" inside the tag, and "something" now displays correctly. I don't see how this is considered normal (at least according to the dataTable documentation), but thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table is empty because there is no `value` attribute. This is a simple mechanism:

1. Build header.
2. For every row build content (but there are no rows, so no content is added).
3. Build footer.

One of the workaround is the one you have used, adding `value=""`, but I think you just shouldn't use `rich:dataTable` is you know that the table will be always empty. You can build the same with `h:panelGrid`.

Moreover you can use `noDataLabel` attribute, which displays something like this:

```
<rich:dataTable noDataLabel="There are no products to display">
    <rich:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Product" />
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="footer">
            <h:outputText value="Product" />
        </f:facet>
    </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>
```

[image: RichFaces - noDataLabel]]

Comment: The reason I didn't put a value at first was because I wanted to see what it would look like before doing anything more. Apparently this was a bad idea. Thank you.